# Android Google plus login button doesn't work

Tags: android, button, authentication, google-plus

I'm trying to implement the login with Google+ in my firt activity of my application. I followed the google dev tutorial but when I click on the SignIn button nothing happens. I think I've made some mistakes, here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

public static final String mAPP_ID = "xxxx";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

private ImageButton googleSignOutButton;

AssetsExtracter mTask;

private MainFragment mainFragment;

static {
    IMetaioSDKAndroid.loadNativeLibs();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
            .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity")
            .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN) 
            .build();
    // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not
    // resolved.
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

    mTask = new AssetsExtracter();
    mTask.execute(0);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
        // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
        // connection dialog.
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                result.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    // Save the intent so that we can start an activity when the user clicks
    // the sign-in button.
    mConnectionResult = result;

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // We've resolved any connection errors.
    mConnectionProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR
            && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPlusClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
            && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        if (mConnectionResult == null) {
            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
        } else {
            try {
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        getParent(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // Try connecting again.
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**EDIT**:
I've discovered that in the onConncectionFailed() method, if I remove the first "if()" that checks if the processDialog is showing, when the application starts, without clicking anything, a dialog of google+ appears asking me to login. this is strange

**EDIT**:
I resolved my problem using a normal Button and implementing onClick on it, following the tutorial of Google Dev

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your application on the Google developers console?  You need to make sure your Android application has an associated client ID with the Google+ API enabled.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

Comment: yes, I followed the tutorial and I created the client ID using the SHA1 digest with keytool. Do I have to put the client ID in the application as a string in string.xml file??

Comment: No, you don't need to add the client ID anywhere.  The client ID is associated with your app because it is signed with your key.  When you created your client ID you should have entered the fingerprint of your app certificate.

Comment: this is what I did, with the SHA1 fingerprint. I don't know why the login doesn't work, and there is nothing on Logcat about errors or exceptions.

Comment: After following all the instructions to the T, I found that my app does not work on my phone running Android 5.1 (BLU), BUT it works as expected on other mobiles which were running Android 4.2 (Huawaii) and Android 4.3 (Samsung). Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging I realised that providing the *release* SHA-1 to the console only gave me the ability to run my project with a working sign-in button if and only I generated a signed APK and installed the APK manually and not through Android Studio. 
I figured changing the SHA-1 to debug was the solution but I wasn't able to change it until now.

To change your SHA-1 from the release version to the debug version so you can install a working/testable apk through Android Studio:

Open Google Cloud Console > Open API Manager > Click on Credentials. 
Under OAuth2.0 Client IDs > click Android Client for your app and change the SHA-1 to your debug version (following these instructions should help you to retrieve your debug SHA-1: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) 
After doing so, save your new credentials in the Cloud Console and return to the screen to generate your configuration file. You should notice your changed SHA-1. Now generate the config file and paste it into **app/..** project directory. Clean, rebuild, and run your project and your signin button should now work as expected.